# Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true

Tags: c#, reflection

I am getting this error on a routine which uses reflection to dump some object properties, something like the code below.

```
MemberInfo[] members = obj.GetType().GetMembers(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) ;

foreach (MemberInfo m in members)
{
    PropertyInfo p = m as PropertyInfo;
    if (p != null)
    {
       object po = p.GetValue(obj, null);

       ...
    }
}
```

The actual error is "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation"
with an inner exception of "Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true."

At this stage in the debugger obj appears as

```
  {Name = "SqlConnection" FullName = "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection"}
```

with the type System.RuntimeType

The method m is {System.Reflection.MethodBase DeclaringMethod}

Note that obj is of type System.RuntimeType and members contains 188 items whereas a simple
typeof(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection).GetMembers(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance) only returns 65.

I tried checking isGenericParameter on both obj and p.PropertyType, but this seems to be false for  most properties including those where p.GetValue works.

So what exactly is a "Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true" and more importantly 
how do I avoid this error without a try/catch?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Firstly, you've made an incorrect assumption, that is, you've assumed that `members` has returned the members of an instance of `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`, which it has not.  What has been returned are the members of an instance of `System.Type`.

From the MSDN documentation for [DeclaringType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.declaringmethod.aspx):

> Getting the `DeclaringMethod` property
> on a type whose  `IsGenericParameter`
> property is false throws an
> `InvalidOperationException`.

So... it's understandable that an `InvalidOperationException` is being thrown, since naturally, you're not dealing with an open generic type here. See [Marc Gravell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346238/method-may-only-be-called-on-a-type-for-which-type-isgenericparameter-is-true/1346266#1346266) for an explanation of open generic types.

Comment: I thinking I am beginning to see the light. It isn't saying that p.GetValue can 'only called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true' but rather that the underlying property represented by p, which in this case is DeclaringMethod, can only be called is Type.IsGenericParameter is true.

Comment: Exactly - that's what "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" means, the "target of an invocation" in this case is the `DeclaringMethod` property getter, and you'd get the same `IsGenericParameter` exception by reading `obj.DeclaringMethod` directly.

Comment: I've marked this answer as my accepted answer as it was the most helpful, but in truth most of the other answers helped as well. So thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 16):

> So what exactly is a "Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true"

That means it is a generic type argument in an open generic type - i.e. where we haven't picked a `T` yet; for example:

```
// true
bool isGenParam = typeof(List<>).GetGenericArguments()[0].IsGenericParameter;

// false (T is System.Int32)
bool isGenParam = typeof(List<int>).GetGenericArguments()[0].IsGenericParameter;
```

So; have you got some open generics hanging around? Perhaps if you can give an example of where you got your `obj` from?

Comment: The OP does state the type of in obj its System.RuntimeType

Comment: From what I can see, the problem isn't so much the existence of open generics, but the existence of normal types :)

Comment: I start with a exception (in this case a SqlException) which is passed to my dump routine. The dump routine is recursive, so the dump is called on all the properties and fields in the exception.

There are a few generics in my code, but no open generics.

What is confusing me is the error seems to say that p.GetValue only works if GenericParameter is true which is plainly not true.

Comment: @sgmoore: What do you thing GetValue is doing?  Its invoking the get operation of property described by the PropertyInfo on the obj.  The PropertyInfo describes the DeclaringMethod of a Type object, hence GetValue calls the get operation of DeclaringMethod which is then failing because obj is not a Generic Type of a Method.

Comment: @anthonywjones. I understand that (now). It seems obvious in hindsight, but it wasn't until I read Eric Smith's answer that it clicked. My only excuse is that the word Method in the error message threw me. (And yes, I understand the properties are effectively a get and set method, but I don't think of properties as methods and assumed the method it was talking about must be the GetValue method)

Answer (score 3):

All the clues are in there.  The type of the obj is the `Type` class itself (or rather the strange RuntimeType derivative).

At the point of failure you loop has arrived the `Type` class property called [`DeclaringMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.declaringmethod.aspx).  However the type that this instance of the `Type` class is describing is `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` which is not a Generic Type of a method.

Hence attempting to invoke the get on DeclaringMethod results in the exception.

The key is you are examining the type of the class `Type`.  Its a bit circular but think of this:-

```
SqlConnection s = new SqlConnection();
Type t = s.GetType()
Type ouch = t.GetType()
```

What is class ouch describing?

Answer (score 1):

**How do I avoid this error without a try/catch?**

You almost certainly can't. When you call `p.GetValue`, you're calling the getter on that property, which could throw any kind of exception. For example, SqlConnection.ServerVersion will throw an exception if the connection is closed, and you have to handle that.

**Where are these extra members coming from?**

Your `obj` already contains the `RuntimeType` object representing `SqlConnection`, rather than an instance of `SqlConnection`. `obj.GetMembers()` would return the 65 members of the `SqlConnection` class, but by calling `GetType()` again, you get the 188 members of `RuntimeType`.

**What is `IsGenericParameter`?**

Instead of representing a class, you can have an instance of `RuntimeType` that represents a generic parameter to a class or method (The `T` and `TOutput` in `List<T>.ConvertAll<TOutput>`. In this case, `DeclaringMethod` on the object representing `TOutput` would let you get a `MethodInfo` object representing the `ConvertAll<>` method. However, when the `RuntimeType` represents a class, the idea of a declaring method makes no sense. That's why reading the property causes the exception that you saw.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was solved by deleting repetitive fields and tables in my model and commented defining query and deleted store: in Model.edmx XML File.