# Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true and The type initializer for 'XYZ' threw an exception

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a set up similar to this:

```
Program.cs
{
     public static void Main(string[] args)
     {
          XYZ.SomeMethod(); //--> XYZ is accessed for the firsttime here
     }

     private void OnDBInstall(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
          //after Db install is complete
          if(success)
          {
               InvokeMethod(SomeEvent) //-->this is the second time XYZ is accessed
          }
     }
}

public static class Utility
{
     public static void InvokeSomeMEthods(EventHandler<T> h)
     {
          if(h!=null)
          {
               foreach(EventHandler<T> eh in h.GetInvocationList())
               {
                   eh.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);
               }
          }
     }
}

public static class XYZ
{
     private static XYZCache _cache = new XYZCache();

     static XYZ()
     {
          SomeEvent += OnSomeEvent;
          _cache.Initialize();
     }

     static void OnSomeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
          _cache.Initialize();
     }

     static void SomeMethod()
     {
          //some db call
     } 
}


internal class XYZCache
{
     internal void Initialize()
     {
          //some db call
     }
}
```

I get multiple exceptions at different stages. When XYZ.SomeMethod() is called the first time, I get, "Cannot open database ".." requested by the login. The login failed". OK this is good because the database doesn't exist at that point.  I should have checked if the DB exist first before making any Db calls. And this exception is left unhandled.

Then the other exceptions I get at eh.Invoke (DB is created and available at this point): "The type initializer for 'XYZ' threw an exception", "Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true.", and I also get "Cannot open database ".." requested by the login. The login failed". When I get these exception, OnSomeEvent in XYZ class is not even invoked so _cache is not accessed.

"The type initializer for 'XYZ' threw an exception" is very misleading since this is not the first time XYZ is accessed.

if XYZ.SomeMethod() is wrapped by a try catch, then everything is good. Is there a way to handle this situation without try catch? I also cannot check for the DB existence because of some weird reason.

Note: I already read this post this is very useful: [Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346238/method-may-only-be-called-on-a-type-for-which-type-isgenericparameter-is-true/1346266#1346266)